# Conditional form actions with jquery show/hide on radios/inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm working on a form that has to show/hide based on a radio/checkbox selections. I have this half working, but I'm running into a number of errors & I'm certain that this code can be optimized/written much more efficiently.

The flow of the form needs to work based off of what checkboxes/radios are selected. I'm not entirely sure the best way to lay this out in a SO post, so Ive commented the html. If I can clarify this in anyway, I will happily do so if someone has a suggestion

In the markup below, I have added comments where I want to render the html. I have a working example of this over at JS Fiddle. You can see that here http://jsfiddle.net/gTAGG/2/

```
<form id="dorm-form" class="order-start form-horizontal form-horizontal-left-align" action="/reservation#hourly" method="GET">

    <!-- SELECT school -->
    <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="school">College town:</label>
          <div class="controls">
               <select name="school" class="span3">
               <option value="">-- Choose your college town--</option>
                      {% for school in schools %}{% if school.name != 'Other' %}<option value="{{ school.id }}">{{ school.name }}</option>{% endif %}{% endfor %}
               </select>
           </div>
     </div>

    <!-- Multiple Checkboxes -->
<div class="control-group">
      <p> Tell us what you need </p>
      <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="Load">
         Load
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="Unload">
           Unload
      </label>
  </div>

    <!-- Multiple Checkboxes -->

    <!-- values are still load & unload. Figure out how these save -->
    <div id="movingtruck" class="control-group">
        <p> Do you need a moving truck (flat rate $125) </p>
        <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="radios" value="Yes" checked="checked">
            Yes
        </label>
        <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="radios" value="No">
            No
        </label>
    </div>

    <!-- If you select either "load" or just "unload" this form should show. If both load & unload are selected, this does not show.-->
    <div id="radios" class="control-group">
        <p> Do you live in a dorm or greekhouse? </p>
        <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="radios" value="Greek" checked="checked">
            Yes
        </label>
        <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="radios" value="NoGreek">
            No
        </label>
    </div>

    <!-- if "yes" is selected above, then this should show. If "no" is selected above, this should hide.-->
    <div id="dorms" class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="dorm">
      <i class="error-warning cb-icon cb-icon-warning"></i>
        Dorm:
      </label>
      <div class="controls">
        <select require="true" name="dorm">
          <option value="">-- Choose your dorm --</option>
          {% for dorm in dorms %}<option value="{{ dorm.id }}">{{ dorm.name }}</option>{% endfor %}
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- if "yes" is selected above, then this should hide. If "no" is selected above, this should hide.-->
    <div id="greek" class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">Greekhouse</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="name of your house" class="input-xlarge">

      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Show when "unload" is checked as well as when "no" selected. If "yes" is selected, this should hide -->
    <div class="row" id="hops">
      <div class="span6 control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="bellhops">
          <i class="error-warning cb-icon cb-icon-warning"></i>
          How many Bellhops?
        </label>
        <div class="controls">
          <select name="bellhops">
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
            <option value="3">Three</option>
            <option value="4">Four</option>
            <option value="5">Five</option>
            <option value="6">Six</option>
          </select>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Show when "unload" is checked as well as when "no" selected. If "yes" is selected, this should hide -->
    <div id="bellhop-hours" class="span6 control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="hours">
        <i class="error-warning cb-icon cb-icon-warning"></i>
        How many hours?
      </label>
      <div class="controls">
        <select name="hours" id="hours">
          <option value="1.5">One and a half</option>
          <option value="2">Two</option>
          <option value="2.5">Two and a half</option>
          <option value="3">Three</option>
          <option value="3.5">Three and a half</option>
          <option value="4">Four</option>
          <option value="4.5">Four and a half</option>
          <option value="5">Five</option>
          <option value="5.5">Five and a half</option>
          <option value="6">Six</option>
          <option value="6.5">Six and a half</option>
          <option value="7">Seven</option>
          <option value="7.5">Seven and a half</option>
          <option value="8">Eight</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- BUTTON -->
    <div class="form-controls">
      <button class="btn btn-lime">Reserve Your Bellhops!</button>
    </div>

    </form>
```

Here is the JS that I am using

```
// Inputs for Load & Unload
    $("input[value=Load]").click(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
       $("#dorms, #greek,").show();
    }else{
        $("#dorms, #greek").hide();
    }
});


$("input[value='Unload']").click(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
       $("#movingtruck").show();
    }else{
        $("#hops, #hours").hide();
    }
});

// Inputs for Do you need a moving truck?

$("input[value='Yes']").click(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
       $("#hops, #bellhop-hours").show();
    }
});

$("input[value='No']").click(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
       $("#hops, #bellhop-hours").show();
    }
});

// Radios for "Do you live in a dorm or greekhouse?"

// Radios arent hiding when selecting "nogreek" Check on radios. 

$("input[value='Greek']").click(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
       $("#dorms, #greek").show();
    }else{
        $("#dorms, #greek, #hops").hide();
    }
});

$("input[value='NoGreek']").click(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
       $("#hops, #hours").show();
    }else{
        $("#dorms, #greek").hide();
    }
});
```

And a tiny bit of CSS

```
/* Hiding form elements */

#greek, #dorm-selector, #hops, #dorms, #hidden, #movingtruck, #bellhop-hours{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a work in progress fiddle which does something similar to yours (well, show and hide and add elements) You can check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/Hux2L/

A question here: i'm not quite sure about your `load` and `unload` and do you want to show and hide accordingly? from what i see, after i clicked on something, something will show up but some won't show anything. ;) it's like a surprise game.

EDIT:

You can give the 2 checkboxes an ID each:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="Load" id="load">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="Unload" id="unload">
```

Then you can specify the condition as :

```
if ($('#load').is(':checked ')&&$('#unload').is(':checked')){
   //do what you want here
   $('#dorms').hide();
   $('#movingtruck').show();

}
```

Comment: haha, the JS is a little broken there I guess. Ill work on fixing that now. The way it should act is if you select "load" or "unload" it should show "do you live in a dorm", but if you select both "load and unload" it should show "do you need a moving truck"

Comment: ah i see :) may be you should hide everything first, then when those conditions is met, `show` it, else, `hide`.

Comment: oh, since it is check box, you should use `.is(:checked)` instead of the value of click i think?

Comment: Do you know it is possible to show & hide based on when two inputs are selected, instead of just one? So if both "load" and "unload" are selected, show some type of content?

Comment: think you're missing a ` </div>` as well under `bellhops` option. Edited and added for you in the code above.